# Apply Autofilter to separate ‘blocks’ of data on same sheet

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

So I have a problem using autofilter.  I have a sheet (sheet1) of data that is imported from elsewhere that gives me 3 separate ‘blocks’ of data in columns A to D comprising 5-12 rows of data each.  There is a ‘gap’ of 3 empty rows in between each block.  I apply an autofilter using Criteria I get from sheet2 cell A2 which uses a dropdown of employees surnames.

I copied some code I found on this site on how to apply autofilter, but the problem is it only applies the filter to the first ‘block’ of data and I want it to apply to the whole sheet to all 3 blocks at the same time.

Can you point out how I can fix my code?

```
Sub FilterByName()

myFilter = Sheets(2).Range("A2").Value

With Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=myFilter
End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CurrentRegion` defines the *contiguous* range you start your code on – that’s where your problem lies.  You could find the last row of data in Sheet1 and define the whole range to filter, alternatively you can actually apply `AutoFilter` to an entire column – which will ignore blank rows.  According to your code, you’re filtering on column `B`.  Please try the following & let me know how it goes.

```
Option Explicit
Sub FilterColumn()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets(1)
Set ws2 = Sheets(2)

Dim myFilter As String
myFilter = ws2.Cells(2, 1).Value2

ws1.Columns(2).AutoFilter 1, myFilter

End Sub
```